# Summarizing the sales data to monthly

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I'm having the following table of data:

```
Customer 14-Sep-12  30-Sep-12   1-oct-12    28-Nov-12   5-Nov-12
ASTDU    4718.00     3885.00     1680.00     3058.00     2147.00
BJURT    3646.00     4557.00     2747.00     3151.00     3511.00
CMTDF    2692.00     2560.00     6821.00     28160.00    6989.00
```

I want to summarize it like the following table. How would I do this?

```
Customer Sep  Oct Nov 
ASTDU 
BJURT 
CMTDF`
```

I used months formula to find out month no. I tried to use sumif(range,critirea,sumrange) formula by using month no as criteria, but I am getting zero as answer.

Comment: Whad did you already try? Why it did not work?

Comment: i used sumif formula on month no critirea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off you really need more detail in your question since it's hard to understand what you've tried (give your formula) but I will give you some info on what I believe the problem to be.

First off `=month` will return the number of the month (1,2,3) not the name (Jan,Feb,Mar).

Second you can't use `month` within `sumif` you either need to have an extra row above your dates giving the month in a number (colour it white so people don't see it) and then you can use sumif.

[image]

Or second you can use an array formula and you don't need the helper row at the top.  Note you don't put in the curly brackets manually. You have to enter the formula by pressing ctrl+shift+enter.

Gordon

[image]